# Too many arguments were passed to the DRILLDOWNLEVEL MDX function. No more than 3 arguments are allowed

Tags: sql-server, mdx, olap, olap-cube, analysisservices

I have faced following exception while run the below query in SQL Server 2008. This problem occurred only in SQL Server 2008. It will executed fine in other SQL Server versions like 2014, 2016.

```
WITH MEMBER   
[Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].&[United States].[West Coast] AS  
[Customer].[Customer Geography].[State-Province].&[OR]&[US] +  
[Customer].[Customer Geography].[State-Province].&[WA]&[US] +  
[Customer].[Customer Geography].[State-Province].&[CA]&[US]  
SELECT [Measures].[Internet Order Count] ON 0,  
DRILLDOWNLEVEL([Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].&[United States],,,INCLUDE_CALC_MEMBERS) on 1  
FROM [Adventure Works]
```

> Query (1, 184) Too many arguments were passed to the DRILLDOWNLEVEL MDX function. No more than 3 arguments are allowed.

Could you please anyone guide me about this?

Comment: Your DRILLDOWNLEVEL call includes this: `,,,`. The function accepts 3 parameters. You are supplying 1 with the country declaration, 2 empty ones, and finally add `INCUDE_CALC_MEMBERS` as a 4th parameter.

Comment: @SchmitzIT But this is working fine in latest versions like SQL Server 2014. Is this a breaking change?

Comment: `Query (1, 183) The dimension '[INCLUDE_CALC_MEMBERS]' was not found in the cube when the string, [INCLUDE_CALC_MEMBERS], was parsed.`                     
                                                                                                                              I get above error when i pass 3 parameters.

Comment: @Manikdan Ram - I don't know if the definition changed between versions, but the formula you have at least makes it look as if you are passing 4 parameters in total. 

I just checked the documentation on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/mdx/drilldownlevel-mdx?view=sql-server-ver15&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-2014, where it actually seems to indicate using it as a 4th parameter is okay, "because the calculated member is at the same level as the non-calculated members".  Could that be your issue?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms144937(v=sql.105)